# doc's Attached behavior vs doc's attached property?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to apply some validation on the entry input, I went to the docs page of the [attached behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/attached)

and did this:

```
public enum TextType { Email, Phone, }
    public static class Validator
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty TextTypeProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
            "TextType", typeof(TextType), typeof(Validator), TextType.Email, propertyChanged: ValidateText);

        public static TextType GetTextType(BindableObject view)
        {
            return (TextType)view.GetValue(TextTypeProperty);
        }

        public static void SetTextType(BindableObject view, TextType textType)
        {
            view.SetValue(TextTypeProperty, textType);
        }
        private static void ValidateText(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var entry = bindable as Entry;
            entry.TextChanged += Entry_TextChanged;
        }

        private static void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var entry = sender as Entry;
            bool isValid = false;
            switch (GetTextType(sender as Entry))
            {
                case TextType.Email:
                    isValid = e.NewTextValue.Contains("@");
                    break;
                case TextType.Phone:
                    isValid = Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, @"^\d+$");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (isValid)
                entry.TextColor = Color.Default;
            else
                entry.TextColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

in XAML:

```
<Entry beh:Validator.TextType="Email" Placeholder="Validate Email"/>
```

but it doesn't work, the setter nor the `propertyChanged` call back are never called,

also what is the difference between this "Attached behavior" and the [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties), the two pages are pretty identical

Answer (score 1):

> what does the logic have to do with the propertyChanged method is not called?

From this MSDN [Attached Behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/attached),you can see that An attached property can define a propertyChanged delegate that will be executed when the value of the property changes.

According to your code, you set TextType=TextType.Email firstly, then you also set

```
<Entry beh:Validator.TextType="Email" Placeholder="Validate Email"/>
```

Validator.TextType="Email", the attached property doesn't change, so PropertyChanged method is not call.

You can modify your code like this, then you will find the propertychanged will be called.

```
<Entry beh:Validator.TextType="Phone" Placeholder="Validate Email"/>
```

Comment: What have you changed? `Phone` instead of `Email`?

Comment: In Validator class, you set TextType property as TextType.Email, you can see it from the code `public static readonly BindableProperty TextTypeProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
            "TextType", typeof(TextType), typeof(Validator), TextType.Email, propertyChanged: ValidateText);` so you need to change TextType as phone,  then the PropertyChanged method will be called.

Comment: Why when `defaultValue`= `null` propertyChanged is not fired?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing to the sample you ignore most of the logic from OnAttachBehaviorChanged in your ValidateText and it is quite necessary:

```
    static void OnAttachBehaviorChanged (BindableObject view, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var entry = view as Entry;
    if (entry == null) {
        return;
    }

    bool attachBehavior = (bool)newValue;
    if (attachBehavior) {
        entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
    } else {
        entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
    }
}
```

Considering the differences, attached properties are something that is applied to a specific control, you can apply behavior technically to any control though probably it will work only on some of them but it may work on multiple control types properly.

Comment: what  does the logic have to do with the `propertyChanged` method is not called?

Comment: @mshwf, are your breakpoints resolved when you debug? Sometimes Xamarin doesn't resolve breakpoints and ignores them. Check if they are filled circles or not while debugging.